# Retrieve all parents, all possible children, sorted and with their "depth"

Tags: ruby, array, ruby-on-rails

I have a model `section` with a column `parent_id` - the only thing identifying a parent/child relationship. I wrote a helper method to output all sections, all their possible subsections and include their "depth".

This is the helper method:

```
# Calls itself for each section recursively to fetch all possible children
def fetch_all_sections(standard, section = nil, depth = 0)
  all_sections = []
  if section.nil?
    rootsections = roots(standard.sections.sorted)
    if ! rootsections.nil?
      rootsections.each do |section|
        all_sections.push(fetch_all_sections(standard, section))
      end
    end
  else
    all_sections.push({:id => section.id, :sortlabel => section.sortlabel, :title => section.title, :depth => depth})
    section.children.sorted.each_with_index do |section, index|
      all_sections.push(fetch_all_sections(standard, section, (depth += 1) - index))
    end
  end
  return all_sections
end
```

`sorted` is a module method which sorts based on the `sort_key` column using regular expressions. The output of `debug(fetch_all_sections(@standard))` is:

```
- - "1 Collaborase Test Document depth: 0"
  - - "1.1 Section One Dot One depth: 1"
  - - "1.a Testing 123 depth: 1"
  - - "1.b Section One dot B depth: 1"
    - - "1.b.1 Testing One B One depth: 2"
- - "2 Identify Project GHG Sources, Sinks, and Reservoirs (SSRs) depth: 0"
  - - "2.a Section Two dot A depth: 1"
- - "3 Identify the Baseline depth: 0"
- - "4 Identify the Baseline GHGs depth: 0"
- - "5 Identify SSRs Relevant for Quantification depth: 0"
  - - "5.1 Section Five Dot One depth: 1"
- - "6 GHG Quantification depth: 0"
- - "7 Monitoring depth: 0"
- - "8 Data and Information Retention depth: 0"
- - "9 QA/QC depth: 0"
```

**My questions is this:**

In this loop:

```
<% fetch_all_sections(@standard).each do |section| %>
  <%= debug section %>
<% end %>
```

I want each section and all their children to be separated. Instead, each section in the above loop contains their children.

Instead of this:

```
--- 
- - :id: 122
    :sortlabel: "5"
    :title: Identify SSRs Relevant for Quantification
    :depth: 0
- - - :id: 412
      :sortlabel: "5.1"
      :title: Section Five Dot One
      :depth: 1
```

I want this:

```
--- 
- - :id: 122
    :sortlabel: "5"
    :title: Identify SSRs Relevant for Quantification
    :depth: 0
---
- - :id: 412
    :sortlabel: "5.1"
    :title: Section Five Dot One
      :depth: 1
```

Comment: Derp. The syntax is `all_sections.push([section.sortlabel, section.title, depth])`. I'll leave the question open to see if anyone comes up with something better.

Comment: I opted for pushing keys for easier retrieval: `all_sections.push({:id => section.id, :sortlabel => section.sortlabel, :title => section.title, :depth => depth})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was the pipe operator! It was of course just doing what I was telling it to - pushing the results of itself onto the current element in the array. Only when the rootsections loop completes does it start a new array element.

The 'pipe' (`|`) is a different array merge operator which appends what's to the right of it onto the end of the array on the left.

```
all_sections | fetch_all_sections(standard, section, depth)
```

The pipe operator changed how depth worked so instead I just counted the number of "." in sortlabel:

```
depth = section.sortlabel.split('.').length -1
```

The full method:

```
# Calls itself for each section recursively to fetch all possible children
def fetch_all_sections(standard, section = nil, depth = 0)
  all_sections = []

  if section.nil?
    rootsections = standard.sections.sorted
    if ! rootsections.nil?
      rootsections.each_with_index do |section, i|
        depth = section.sortlabel.split('.').length - 1
        all_sections << fetch_all_sections(standard, section, depth).first
      end
    end
  else

    all_sections << {:id => section.id, :sortlabel => section.sortlabel, :title => section.title, :depth => depth}

    section.children.sorted.each do |section|
      all_sections | fetch_all_sections(standard, section)
    end
  end

  return all_sections
end
```

If someone seeing this is considering something similar but starting from scratch, consider an Active Record Nesting gem: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting

UPDATE: I added .first within the rootsections loop. This is because I inadvertently built an array of arrays, each containing 1 hash. What I wanted was an array of hashes. Much easier retrieval now!